# Change the color of UIButton in IBOutletCollection

Tags: swift

I have an IBOutletCollection of UIButton:

```
@IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]!
```

and a function for a tap:

```
@IBAction func button_Tap(_ sender: UIButton) {

    for button in buttons {
        if button.tag == sender.tag { button.backgroundColor = .blue }
        else {button.backgroundColor = .white}

    }
}
```

The outlets are connected in a storyboard.

I need to change the color of the buttons on a button tap. When tap on the first button, it should turn to the blue color and other buttons should be white.

My code does not work correctly. When I tap on the button it turns blue color. But when I tap on another button, the first button does not change the color to white.

Can someone help me to solve this problem? Thanks.

**Update:**

I also have this code in `class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource`:

```
let cellIdentifiers:[String] = ["FirstPercentCell", "SecondPercentCell", "ThirdPercentCell", "FourthPercentCell", "FifthPercentCell"]

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return cellIdentifiers.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let collectionCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellIdentifiers[indexPath.item], for: indexPath)
    return collectionCell
}
```

So maybe the problem in this part?

Comment: Ah. So I'm going to guess that each of these button is in a different collection view cell. In that case what you're doing is completely wrong and what I said (and all the other answers up to this point) is totally irrelevant.

Comment: I'm not sure that I need this part of code in a ViewController. I took information from different tutorials. Can I somehow fix this?

Comment: Yes. Each of these button is i a different collection view cell.

Comment: Then, as I said, if your goal is to change the color of the buttons in different cells when you tap the button in one cell, you can't do it with an outlet collection. You have to deal with each cell. You must store the desired button color _in the data model_ and _reload the cells_.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
@IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]!
var lastTappedButton: UIButton?

@IBAction func button_Tap(_ sender: UIButton) {

    for button in buttons {
        if let lastTappedButton = lastTappedButton, lastTappedButton != sender {
            button.backgroundColor = .white
        }
        if button.tag == sender.tag { 
            button.backgroundColor = .blue 
            lastTappedButton = button
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have tried your code. The problem is the same. The buttons turn blue, but do not change to white.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have updated the main post with the part of ViewController class. Can you check please?

Answer (score 0):

For this to work

1- All buttons should be connected to

```
 @IBOutlet var buttons: [UIButton]!
```

2-  All buttons should be connected to

```
@IBAction func button_Tap(_ sender: UIButton)
```

3- Every button should have a different tag for example 0,1,2

4- You can use this

```
@IBAction func button_Tap(_ sender: UIButton) {
  self.buttons.forEach { $0.backgroundColor = $0 === sender ? .blue : .white  }
}
```

Result

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does not work in my case. I have updated the post and I have added the part of ViewController class. Maybe the problem is here.